# can't display Blob image on iis server

Tags: angular

in angular 7 
i need to display profile picture from databae by using Blob object and createObjectURL
it works fine on local host mood 
but not working when release production version on iis server 
can any one help me for this problem

my angualr code

```
  this.usersService.prieveiewFileDB(this.AttachId).subscribe(Attach=>{
console.log(Attach)
  let file = new Blob([Attach], { type:"image"});   
  let unsafeImageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);      
  this.imageUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(unsafeImageUrl);   
})  
});
```

HTML

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="profile">
   <span class="img_prf">
    <img [src]="imageUrl" alt="image">
     </span>
     <span class="usr_name">{{userName}}</span>
   <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your image type? example type: "`image/png`"

```
let file = new Blob([Attach], { type:"image/png"});
```

or

```
 let file = new Blob([Attach], { type:"image/jpg"});
```

Also check MIME type in IIS

[image]